# Passing values from react file to a pain html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

How could I pass data/values from my react app to a static html file?
For example: I have some that I get from a form in a react app.js file. Now i want to pass that data to a plain html file. How could I do That?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Idea that comes to my mind is that you can try to store that form data in the local storage, on the HTML file read from the Local Storage, This way you can achieve what you are looking for. Below is the code for that

React Code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const FormCompenent = () => {
 const [value, setValue] = useState();
 handleSubmit = () => {
  const savedValue = {
    value
  }

  localStorage.setItem('value', JSON.strigify(savedValue));
  window.location = '/newhtmlpage.html'
 }

 return (<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}><input type="text" onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value) } value={value} /> </form> )
}
```

HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    let valueFromReact = localStorage.getItem('value'); // this will get you the value shared from react
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not sure why you want to do that, but this is one of option you can try.